# WSL2 dynamic File Paths based on the username for linux and windows

Tags: linux, shell-script, ubuntu, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've created a bash script and would like to have a dynamic file path for windows and linux part of WSL2.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create the workspace
mkdir /mnt/c/Users/FINIX/Documents/Workspace/test/

# Go to the workspace
cd /mnt/c/Users/FINIX/Documents/Workspace/test/

# Create the temp file to store the branches
touch /home/finix/test.txt

# Clone the repo
git clone https://github.com/test/test.git

# Going to the downloaded repo
cd /mnt/c/Users/FINIX/Documents/Workspace/test/TEST/
```

I'd like to dynamically change the username finix to whatever username of the machine would be from the linux side and windows side of WSL2.

Comment: Does it work if you just replace `/mnt/c/Users/FINIX` with `~/` or `$HOME`? So `mkdir /mnt/c/Users/FINIX/Documents/Workspace/test/` would become `mkdir ~/Documents/Workspace/test/` or `mkdir "$HOME/Documents/Workspace/test/"`.  I don't have access to WSL to test.

Comment: No it didn't work. 

finix@DESKTOP-67OJELR:/mnt/c/Users/FINIX/Documents/Scripts$ mkdir ~/Documents/Workspace/test/
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/finix/Documents/Workspace/test/’: No such file or directory
finix@DESKTOP-67OJELR:/mnt/c/Users/FINIX/Documents/Scripts$ mkdir "$HOME/Documents/Workspace/test/"
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/finix/Documents/Workspace/test/’: No such file or directory

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include this. From your output, it looks like your WSL home directory is `/home/finix/`. If you simply use `mkdir -p` instead of `mkdir` it should work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a better way, but here's what I came up with:

To retrieve the Windows user name from within bash:

`winuser=$(powershell.exe -c "Write-Host -NoNewLine ([Environment]::UserName)")`

You should then be able to use that to dynamically create the directory, like so:

`mkdir /mnt/c/Users/${winuser}/Documents/Workspace/test/`

The Linux user is much easier.  That one can, as @terdon was alluding to, be simply:

`touch ${HOME}/test.txt`

Or, alternatively, `touch /home/${USER}/test.txt`.

Of course, the Windows side assumes that the Windows home is always `/mnt/C/Users/`*`username`*

If it's somewhere else, then you'd need the PowerShell incantation to get the user's Windows home directory.  That would be:

`winhome==$(powershell.exe -c 'Write-Host -NoNewLine  $env:userprofile' | xargs -0 wslpath)` (Thanks @Panki for that answer).

Comment: Thanks NotTheDr01ds it works!!!

Comment: `powershell.exe -c 'echo $env:userprofile' | xargs -0 wslpath` returns the Windows profile path as WSL equivalent

Comment: Thanks @Panki - Oddly I was getting empty results when using $env variables when I first tried yesterday, which is why I switched to [Environment] instead (where UserProfile isn't available).  Now it seems to be working, so I'm not sure what I was doing wrong.  I'll update my answer with your contribution!